# How do I store both text and binary files in an hsqldb database?

Tags: text, binary, hsqldb

I would like to give two API functions to store files in a DB - one accepting a `byte[]` (or an `InputStream`) and another one accepting a `String`. I wonder how to implement such an API.

I see the following options:

1. Define two fields - one a BLOB for binary files and another one a CLOB - for text files. Then I could use `PreparedStatement.setBytes` (or `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream`) for BLOBs and `PreparedStatement.setString` for CLOBs. I do not like having two fields.
2. Use `String.getBytes()` to convert the given `String` to `byte[]`, thus coming back to the binary case. I do not like the need to convert a `String` to the `byte[]`.

I was wondering whether there is a solution which does not require two fields and avoids the extra byte buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java String and Clob are Unicode and stored as two-byte characters. Therefore some conversion is necessary if you want to store these values in a byte[], or Blob.

Therefore the best approach is to use two separate fields, one for BLOB and the other for CLOB values.